# Should decltype(foo(1)) instantiate the constexpr function template foo?

Tags: c++, templates, clang, language-lawyer, constexpr

The following code compiles with with gcc and MSVC, but fails using clang I tested with clang-3.5 and current trunk).

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto wrong = false;

template <typename T>
constexpr auto foo(const T t) -> int
{
  static_assert(wrong<T>, "");
  return {};
}

using F = decltype(foo(1));

int main() {}
```

clang instantiates the function body and stumbles over the `static_assert`. gcc and MSVC just look at the function declaration and ignore the `static_assert` in the body.

If you remove the constexpr, all compilers compile the code just fine.

Question:
Is decltype allowed to look into the function body if the return type is declared?

I am looking for a reference to the respective section in the standard.

Comment: I think a better way to ask this is: does `decltype` trigger a template instantiation?

Comment: @BoPersson The compiler cannot tell without instantiating the body. There could be a specialization of `wrong` that is `true`.

Comment: @RyanHaining In most cases, it does not. As written in the question: If you remove the `constexpr`, no compiler instantiates the body.

Comment: "**[temp.inst]/3** ... the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist." That would seem to suggest that, if a piece of code would compile with only the declaration of a function template available but not the definition, then that piece of code shouldn't trigger an implicit instantiation. Clang violates this invariant - works [with declaration alone](http://rextester.com/RZQYP61888), fails [with definition](http://rextester.com/KESGH8058). Looks like a bug to my untrained eye.

Comment: Searching the clang bug database, I learned that there is an unresolved core issue on this topic: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1581

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*History:* As noted in comments, this issue was raised as [CWG issue 1581](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1581).  In a [isocpp.org thread](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/6udLpHDvShU), Columbo argued that the code was valid because templates are never instantiated inside unevaluated operands, however [on a clang bug report](https://reviews.llvm.org/D13386), "rsmith" countered that some `decltype` expressions definitely did require template instantiation.

The clang thread temporarily resolved the issue by coming up with their own (non-standard) criteria for when `decltype` would instantiate a `constexpr` template. Since version 4.0, clang does compile the code successfully.

---

Richard Smith of WG21 has started to address the issue as of November 2017, with [P0859](https://wg21.link/p0859).  This adds new text to [expr.const] which implement the behaviour of clang as discussed above:

> An expression is *potentially constant evaluated* if it is:
>
> - a potentially-evaluated expression ([basic.def.odr]),
> - a *constraint-expression*, including one formed from the *constraint-logical-or-expression* of a *requires-clause*,
> - an immediate subexpression of a *braced-init-list*[ *Footnote:* Constant evaluation may be necessary to determine whether a narrowing conversion is performed ([dcl.init.list]). ],
> - an expression of the form `&` *cast-expression* that occurs within a templated entity[ *Footnote:* Constant evaluation may be necessary to determine whether such an expression is value-dependent ([temp.dep.constexpr]). ], or
> - a subexpression of one of the above that is not a subexpression of a nested unevaluated operand.

A function or variable is *needed for constant evaluation* if it is:

> - a constexpr function that is named by an expression ([basic.def.odr]) that is potentially constant evaluated, or
> - a variable whose name appears as a potentially constant evaluated expression that is either a constexpr variable or is of non-volatile const-qualified integral type or of reference type.

And [temp.inst] is modified to say that a template specialization is instantiated *if its definition affects the semantics of the program*, which means that it's *needed for constant evaluation* as defined above, even if it isn't actually needed, so to speak.

The ODR is modified to avoid Columbo's objection.

---

The recommended changes on that proposal do appear in N4727, which is a post-C++17 draft.  So I assume they have been accepted even though the P0859 link and the CWG defect list don't say so yet.

Under these changes, your code `decltype(foo(1))`, the expression `foo(1)` is NOT *potentially constant evaluated* (because it does not match any of the bullet points above), so the template must not be instantiated, and the code, with a modification to avoid [dcl.constexpr]/6, **should compile successfully**.

(C++17 dcl.constexpr/6 says that a template is ill-formed NDR if there are no valid specializations; which is true for `foo`, however this can be fixed by adding `template <> constexpr auto wrong<float> = true;` for example).