# Is a function definition required to be instantiated when there is no need to check for narrowing?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, narrowing

Consider the following program:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr int f() 
{
    T{}.i; // error if instantiated with [T = double]
    return 42;
}

constexpr void g(char);

using U = decltype( g( {f<double>()} ) );
```

To my understanding, the last line is an error because the call to `f<double>()` is within a brace initializer, and even though `f<T>` returns an `int`, the value of the returned `int` is needed to decide if it can be narrowed to a `char` as expected by `g`. This requires the definition of `f` to be instantiated with `double`, which causes an error. Both gcc and clang reject this code.

---

However, if the definition of `g` is changed to accept an `int` parameter:

```
constexpr void g(int);
```

then it seems that there is no need to instantiate the definition of `f`, since the narrowing conversion *must* succeed. Indeed, gcc accepts this, but clang still instantiates `f` with `double` and rejects the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/TbGKPz). Additionally, if `f` is only declared, but not defined, clang accepts the code, which implies that the definition is not needed, and shouldn't be instantiated.

Is my reasoning correct, and this is a clang bug, or is instantiation required, and this is actually a gcc bug?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593515/should-decltypefoo1-instantiate-the-constexpr-function-template-foo) might help

Comment: @nop666 It's related, but the code there is definitely valid (and is accepted by both compilers). In this case, there is an additional brace initializer which changes the rules I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [CWG #1581](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1581) I think, resolved by [P0859](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0859r0.html).

[temp.inst/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-5) says:

> Unless a function template specialization is a declared specialization, the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist or if the existence of the definition affects the semantics of the program.

Does the existence affect the semantics of the program?

[temp.inst/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-8) says:

> The existence of a definition of a variable or function is considered to affect the semantics of the program if the variable or function is needed for constant evaluation by an expression ([expr.const]), even if constant evaluation of the expression is not required or if constant expression evaluation does not use the definition.

Is it needed for constant evaluation by an expression?

[expr.const/15.6-7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#15.6) says:

> A function or variable is needed for constant evaluation if it is:
>
> - a constexpr function that is named by an expression that is potentially constant evaluated, or
> - a variable whose name appears as a potentially constant evaluated expression that is either a constexpr variable or is of non-volatile const-qualified integral type or of reference type.

Is it named by an expression that is potentially constant evaluated?

[expr.const/15.1-15.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#15) says:

> An expression or conversion is potentially constant evaluated if it is:
>
> - a manifestly constant-evaluated expression,
> - a potentially-evaluated expression,
> - an immediate subexpression of a braced-init-list,
> - an expression of the form & cast-expression that occurs within a templated entity, or
> - a subexpression of one of the above that is not a subexpression of a nested unevaluated operand.

It is an immediate subexpression of a braced-init-list.

Comment: So you're saying the code is invalid, and it's a gcc bug?

Comment: Yes. Instantiation is required. The paper p0859 references the potential need for narrowing as the reason for including that clause. The code is invalid and it is a gcc bug. And p0859 I think was adopted somewhere around ~2017 from what I could find.

Comment: To share a couple other things I learned: gcc's DR status page lists cwg1851 as open: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-dr-status.html and I could not find a relevant gcc bug. However, the adoption of p0859 is referenced in the constexpr invoke paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1065r2.html

Comment: This is helpful information, thanks. I think I agree that this is invalid. So the fact that clang accepts [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6TqrP1) is a bug, right? Since the definition is needed and doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, it would seem to be a bug.